# Installing instiki on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, wiki

I am attempting to install [instiki](http://www.instiki.org) on Windows 7 and am hitting a roadblock.

I have the following installed:

- Ruby 1.9.2
- Rails 2.3.4
- SQLite 3
- Latest [Development Kit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)

I ran the bundler and all gems were installed.  When I run the *.bat file I get the following error:

> ruby.exe script\server -e production
>   :29:in
>   `require': no such file to load --
>   script/../config/boot (LoadError)
>           from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`
>   require'
>           from script/server:2:in 'main'

Comment: I'm not sure instiki has been updated to work with Ruby 1.9.2, have you tried downgrade to 1.8.7?

Comment: That did it!  Please add this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Instiki has not been updated to work with Ruby 1.9.2

I would recommend downgrade to Ruby 1.8.7 and try again.

You can find installers for it at [RubyInstaller website](http://rubyinstaller.org/).